# Duplicate symbol caused by inline extern

Tags: objective-c, import, inline, extern

FMParallaxChild.h

```
typedef struct {
    // ...
} FMParallaxSetting;

inline extern FMParallaxSetting FMParallaxSettingMake(CGPoint ratio, CGPoint startPos, CGPoint offset, CGPoint relVel, int zOrder);
inline extern FMParallaxSetting FMParallaxSettingMake(CGPoint ratio, CGPoint startPos, CGPoint offset, CGPoint relVel, int zOrder) {
    // ...
}
```

FMParallax.h

```
#import "FMParallaxChild.h"
....
```

MyController.h

```
#import "FMParallax.h"
....
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "MyController.h"
....
```

From this simplified setup I am getting a duplicate symbol linker error:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _FMParallaxSettingMake in MyController.o and AppDelegate.o
```

I can't find any import loops and I only import `FMParallaxChild.h` in a single place, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare it as `static inline` for c or objc:

```
static inline FMParallaxSetting
  FMParallaxSettingMake(CGPoint ratio,
                        CGPoint startPos,
                        CGPoint offset,
                        CGPoint relVel,
                        int zOrder) {
  // ...
}
```

or just `inline` for c++ or objc++:

```
inline FMParallaxSetting
  FMParallaxSettingMake(CGPoint ratio,
                        CGPoint startPos,
                        CGPoint offset,
                        CGPoint relVel,
                        int zOrder) {
  // ...
}
```

of course, with c++ and objc++, your program will fall back on the One Definition Rule in this case (which is a good default).

The problem as it is, is that it will be exported for each translation it is visible (`#include`d) in.

Comment: @Aram then you're probably *not* compiling it as c++ or objc++.

Comment: bingo, renamed to .mm and all is well, thanks! Just out of curiosity, what effect does using `static` have in this case?

Comment: @Aram oh, my point was to declare it `static inline` for C and ObjC. In that case, you would not need to rename files or compile them as objc++ (unless you want that).

Comment: hmm, I tried static inline but got the same issue, I'll stil with compiling with obj++ for now

Comment: hmmkay - that's not supposed to happen =\

Comment: not sure, it might be something else, in any case box2d needs me to use obj++ so no probs there :P